# Accessing files on remote machine

Tags: c#, .net, impersonation

I am using c# to access some files sitting in remote machine. I use the impsersonation to login to the remote machine. Through impersonation I am using the correct user and password with no domain name. However, I am getting the following error.

> Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.

When I RDB to the IIS server (using my user credentials) where my project and above c# program is running and from there if I manually try to access that same remote server, then I am able to access that remote server. Also, it does not ask me the user/password when I map to that location. Can anyone please help me to troubleshoot this issue. Please let me know if any additional info is required. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Is an asp.net application running over IIS?.
Check the Application Identity, depending on the version. Also, the Identity of the Application pool where you are running it.

Comment: Also, forgot to mention that when I run the project through my local machine I am able to access the remote server. The same project once deployed to the server then I am not able to access...How to check the Application Identity. My project is .net mvc running in .net framework 4.5

Comment: @celerno - Application pool identity the project is running in is **ApplicationPoolIdentity**. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, right there. You can change it and set your own user and password. Also, you need to set it in format domain\user.

Answer (score 0):

The domain name needs to be the machine name of the remote machine.